# Fit multiple 3d circle to features in the point cloud

Tags: curve-fitting, point-clouds

Situations:
I would like to fit 3d circles for the outer circle and also to the other 2 inner circular features.  With  pyrsc.Circle() i am able to fit the outer circle. I would like to fit similar 3d circle to the innner features as well. The point cloud is of a component in real time, so i know the dimension of the three features from the measurement. So i would like to 3d fit and correct it using RANSAC or least square based on the known dimension. Basically at the end i would like to have a clean point cloud which i am expecting to obtain from the fitted circle.

Problem:
I am able to fit only the outer cicle using library pyrsc. How can i fit a 3D circle to all the three features and minimise the error using the known dimensions?

First part of the code generates a dummy point cloud of the present case. Alternative for actual case, you may also refer to the points (N,3) from the file through the link [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/cj7grm97aprf2eo/fit3D.txt/file).

Many thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pyransac3d as pyrsc
import open3d as o3d


### Creating dummpy poitn cloud which closely matches the current problem. Please run the code to creat the point cloud
# Parameters
radius = 25
num_points = 1000
small_circle_points = 500
noise_std_xy = 0.1
noise_std_z = 0.1
num_small_circles = 2

# Generate circle points
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_points)
x = radius * np.cos(theta)
y = radius * np.sin(theta)
z = np.zeros_like(x)

# Add noise to outer circle
x += np.random.normal(0, noise_std_xy, num_points)
y += np.random.normal(0, noise_std_xy, num_points)
z += np.random.normal(0, noise_std_z, num_points)

# Generate small circles
for i in range(num_small_circles):
    if i == 0:
        small_radius = 3
    else:
        small_radius = 5

    small_theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, small_circle_points)
    small_x = small_radius * np.cos(small_theta)
    small_y = small_radius * np.sin(small_theta)
    small_z = np.zeros_like(small_x)

    # Add noise to inner circles
    small_x += np.random.normal(0, noise_std_xy, 
    small_circle_points)
    small_y += np.random.normal(0, noise_std_xy, 
    small_circle_points)
    small_z += np.random.normal(0, noise_std_z, 
    small_circle_points)

    # Shift one of the circles to a non-concentric position
    if i == 0:
        shift = 12
        small_x += shift
        small_y += shift

    # Add small circles to the point cloud
    x = np.concatenate((x, small_x))
    y = np.concatenate((y, small_y))
    z = np.concatenate((z, small_z))

# Plot the point cloud
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=1)

# Set axes labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('3D Point Cloud')

# Show the plot
plt.show()


points = np.column_stack((x, y, z))

##### Fitting 3D circle to the point cloud 
#########################

sourcepcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
sourcepcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([sourcepcd])
cir = pyrsc.Circle()
center,normal,radius,inliers = cir.fit(points, thresh=0.4, maxIteration=10000)

inline = sourcepcd.select_by_index(inliers).paint_uniform_color([1, 0, 0])

R = pyrsc.get_rotationMatrix_from_vectors([0, 0, 1], normal)

mesh_circle = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_torus(torus_radius=radius, 
tube_radius=0.1)
mesh_circle.compute_vertex_normals()
mesh_circle.paint_uniform_color([0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
mesh_circle = mesh_circle.rotate(R, center=[0, 0, 0])
mesh_circle = mesh_circle.translate((center[0], center[1], center[2]))
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh_circle, sourcepcd])
```

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid not many people are going to want to download that file from mediafire. Is there a way you can rephrase your question so that it's possible to read it, understand it and answer it without downloading that file? Perhaps making up a similar but smaller artificial pointcloud and including the points of that smaller cloud directly in your post?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to isolate the features from each other using algorithm such as DBSCAN and then use the pyrsc.Circle()  individually on each feature to obtain the center and radius of each featur. Is there a more efficient way to solve this ?